# Additional keyword arguments in seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to find out how matplotlib and seaborn plotting functions are associated. Particularly, I'd like to know what pyplot arguments can be passed into keyword dicts `marginal_kws` and `annot_kws` in function `seaborn.jointplot()`.

Suppose we have DataFrame `data` with columns `c0` and `c1`. I guessed that `joint_kws` accepts arguments from `pyplot.hexbin()`, so when I tried to tune the appearance with arguments from there, it worked fine:

```
import seaborn as sns   
sns.jointplot('c0', 'c1', data=data,  kind='hex',
               joint_kws={'gridsize':100, 'bins':'log', 'xscale':'log', 'yscale':'log'})
```

Then I tried to set log scale at histogram axes with an argument `log=True` from `pyplot.hist()`:

```
    sns.jointplot('c0', 'c1', data=data,  kind='hex',
                   joint_kws={'gridsize':100, 'bins':'log', 'xscale':'log', 'yscale':'log'}, 
                   marginal_kws={'log':True})
```

This results in

```
TypeError: distplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'log'
```

How to put it right?

P.S. This question is not about setting log scales in seaborn (with `JointGrid`, i know), but rather about passing matplotlib arguments into seaborn functions as a whole.

Comment: I can see that you are using `jointplot` but why is the error arising on `distplot`?

Comment: I didn't delve in the source code, but I suppose histograms at the margins of `jointplot` are constructed via `distplot`. Also I thought that `marginal_kws` corresponds to `{hist, kde, rug, fit}_kws` in `distplot`, but it seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dictionary of keyword arguments gets passed to `distplot`, which takes a dictionary for `hist_kws`. So you'll have to do something like `marginal_kws={'hist_kws': {'log': True}}`. With that said, shared log axes remain an enduring headache with `jointplot`, and I couldn't get something that looked good out of the box when adapting your code. Some tweaking might get it working, though.

It may also be useful to try and use `JointGrid` [directly](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/axis_grids.html#plotting-bivariate-data-with-jointgrid-and-jointplot) to avoid this kind of complexity.